# How do i check for a pattern in a text input in jquery?

Tags: jquery, regex

here is the table:-

```
var thetable = "";//the table
thetable= thetable + "<tr><th>Audit ID</th><th>Date Modified</th>   <th>Auditor</th><th>Franchisee Name</th><th>Store ID</th><th>Template Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
```

The regex used below I'm using extracts the  pairs but only for a pre-defined string, when i'm attempting to use this technique on input text the extraction automatically stops after entering the first character because the match fails. Is there anyway to get around this? any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var str = "Franchisee Name:Dave+ Monkey:dd";
var myRegexp = new RegExp(/([^+]+):([^+]+)\+?/g);
var match = myRegexp.exec(str);
var colmNames=[],colmValues=[];
while ( match != null) {
  colmNames.push(match[1]);// matches column names
  colmValues.push(match[2]);// matches column values
  match = myRegexp.exec(str);
}
```

Comment: This works theorycally: https://regex101.com/r/fP1gV9/1 . The result is: MATCH 1
1. [0-15] `Franchisee Name`
2. [16-20] `Dave`
MATCH 2
1. [21-28] `Monkey`
2. [29-31] `dd`

Comment: See [this demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/uqmb6zu8/) - it is matching some strings. Is that expected behavior?